# How can I make my Python library with TensorFlow dependencies adaptable for both CPU and GPU versions using Setuptools?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, setuptools, pep

I am building a python library that would be deployed as a python package on PyPI.
The tool I'm using as build system is Setuptools. The library is supposed to work with TensorFlow as a dependency so it is pretty straightforward to add it to the project:

```ini
[project]
...
dependencies = [
    "tensorflow >= 2.11.0",
]
```

Now, the problem is that my library is able to work both with `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` and I would like to deliver a python package that, as default, has `tensorflow` as dependency but letting the user select a different "flavor" (in my case for using the `tensorflow-gpu` and taking advantage of the GPU on the tensor computations).

I've gone trough the documentation of [Setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html) but I couldn't find any help.
As a possible solution I thought that using the section `[project.optional-dependencies]`, could solve my problem, for example setting a field as follows:

```ini
[project.optional-dependencies]
gpu = ["tensorflow-gpu >= 2.11.0"]
```

I could run `pip install myLibrary[gpu]` to also include the optional dependencies, however, the required dependencies (i.e. `tensorflow`) would aways be installed and that's not the behavior I'm expecting.

The other drastic way of solving this problem would be to ship two different libraries (`myLibrary` and `myLibrary-gpu`) but I think it is not an elegant way of managing this situation, especially because the code inside the library is exactly the same for both versions.

Any help on that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand why people still use `tensorflow-gpu` package. TF already merged the CPU/GPU packages for a while now, and we've been training on the GPU using TF 2.11.x+ for years now.

Comment: @Mazyod, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem, it was hard to find an elegant solution. This is the best solution I have so far. Copy the code below into `setup.py` and modify it so that you can append the right TensorFlow package in the dependencies list depending on the subprocess output.

Since python3+ ships with `subprocess`:

```html
import subprocess

# Run the 'nvidia-smi' command
command = "nvidia-smi"

# Python >= 3.7
result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

# Otherwise
# result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)


# Check if the command was successful
if result.returncode == 0:
    # Print the output of the 'nvidia-smi' command
    print("nvidia-smi output:")
    print(result.stdout)
    dependencies = ["tensorflow-gpu >= 2.11.0"]
else:
    # Print any errors that occurred
    print("Error running nvidia-smi:")
    print(result.stderr)
    dependencies = [
        "tensorflow >= 2.11.0",
    ]
```

Note: This is not a general solution because running `nvidia-smi` may not be possible for everyone due to permission issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've also thought about a similar solution. If there is no other elegant way, I will opt for this solution.